# Where can I find Solaris patch clusters for Solaris 2.6?

Tags: solaris, patch-management

One of my customers is working on a product which can virtualize old Solaris environments and run them on current, supported Solaris platforms.

Of course to do this, we need to run an assortment of old Solaris platforms, and by "old" I mean Solaris 2.6.  We have the OSs and can install them, that's no problem.

The issue we are facing is that several of the applications we are trying to install on top of this platform require patches be applied to the base OS installation before the application will install itself.

Sun/Oracle is not being helpful; Oracle is still digesting their purchase of Sun and over the last six months their reps have not been able to figure out what to sell my customer in order for them to have the same level of access to this historical information that we had pre-acquisition.

Does anyone know where I might find a copy of the latest Recommended patch cluster for Solaris 2.6?

Comment: I assume you're registered with Oracle; what happens when you go through the sunsolve.sun.com redirect?

Comment: We only see the patches for 8 and above.  Oracle has told us they can't sell us access to these at any price, they don't officially exist any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend: I found what I was looking for on http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.sun.co.uk/patchroot/clusters/